# iterating through a dynamic object from a webresponse

Tags: c#, json

I am for an id field that is contained in this result set that comes from a web response which I store as a dynamic object.

```
{
  "filterFields": [
    {
      "connectionName": "metis_dev",
      "querySourceCategoryName": "dbo",
      "sourceFieldName": "DealerGroupId",
      "sourceFieldVisible": true,
      "sourceFieldFilterable": true,
      "sourceDataObjectName": "Dealers",
      "sourceDataObjectFullName": "metis_dev.dbo.Dealers",
      "querySourceName": "Dealers",
      "dataType": "Numeric",
      "isParameter": false,
      "isCalculated": false,
      "calculatedTree": null,
      "compareFieldCalculatedTree": null,
      "compareValueCalculatedTree": null,
      "compareField": null,
      "selected": false,
      "dataFormat": null,
      "reportId": null,
      "useMappedFieldAlias": false,
      "uniqueId": null,
      "comparisionValue": null,
      "inTimePeriodType": null,
      "valueInTimePeriod": null,
      "hasModifiedCalculatedTree": false,
      "isHiddenFilter": false,
      "isInheritableFilter": false,
      "isOveridingInheritedFilter": false,
      "operatorName": "Equals (Manual Entry No Auto-Complete)",
      "type": 0,
      "isRunningField": false,
      "isCompositeField": false,
      "isDrillDown": false,
      "originalDataType": null,
      "isReGroupField": false,
      "filterId": "3ab260ff-6894-4f23-ab78-5b4db43ae65e",
      "reportFieldAlias": null,
      "reportPartTitle": null,
      "querySourceFieldId": "d313dc65-3d63-4682-8c80-6ab0f235b1d7",
      "querySourceType": "Table",
      "querySourceId": "ac13435a-98b1-4ea9-97af-815b67842334",
      "relationshipId": null,
      "alias": "DealerGroupId",
      "position": 1,
      "visible": true,
      "required": false,
      "cascading": true,
      "operatorId": "5b654e75-d293-4e7e-9102-cdb74286e717",
      "operatorSetting": null,
      "value": "4967",
      "dataFormatId": null,
      "sortType": "ASC",
      "fontFamily": "Roboto",
      "fontSize": 14,
      "textColor": "#000",
      "backgroundColor": "#fff",
      "fontBold": false,
      "fontItalic": false,
      "fontUnderline": false,
      "querySourceUniqueName": "[con;#0].[cat;#0].[Dealers]",
      "querySourceFieldName": "DealerGroupId",
      "comparisonFieldUniqueName": "",
      "isNegative": false,
      "filterLookupType": 0,
      "filterLookupStatus": 0,
      "canExecuteLookup": false,
      "useLookup": true,
      "id": "b7997ac6-442e-4def-a378-4212ae58b48f",
      "state": 0,
      "deleted": false,
      "inserted": true,
      "version": 5,
      "created": "2019-06-13T15:17:27.943-05:00",
      "createdBy": "Sid Shrivastav",
      "modified": "2019-06-26T03:09:25.613-05:00",
      "modifiedBy": null
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am after is the id field where the value in the collection is as 
`"id": "b7997ac6-442e-4def-a378-4212ae58b48f"`.

```
dynamic responseItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(GetResponse());

if (responseItems != null)
{
    foreach (var item in responseItems)
    {
        var root = JObject.Parse(item.Root.ToString()).Children();
    }
}
```

When I hover over the root object at the run time, one of the value is the above `filterFields` object. But when I say `foreach(var filterField in root.filterFields)`, then I get an error as `filterField` does not exist in the result. How should I go about accessing the `filterFields` collection so I could get to the "id" property that I am looking for? I would want to loop through the `filterFields` from the result which I am not able to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. Had to cast the item as JToken and that did it.

```
JObject root= JObject.Parse(item.Root.ToString());
                foreach (JToken rootItem in root.SelectToken("filterFields"))
                {
                   var id = rootItem["id"];
                }
```